# Can I somehow hook a variable?

Tags: hooks, variables, variable-watchers

So a function is called when the variable value is changed?

`add-hook` seems to only accept functions.

Comment: You gotta read the manual. I recommend [chapter 12.9 Running a function when a variable is changed](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Watching-Variables.html).